# Promise-like syntax for JavaScript UI events

Tags: javascript, promise, callback, dom-events, es6-promise

Promises seem to be a nice improvement on the callback mechanism. Chaining, error handling, escape from callback-hell, more readable, etc. However, they're meant for asynchronous operations that only happen once. So it doesn't make sense to use promises to deal with a `mouseover` event where you want to highlight a DOM element whenever someone hovers their mouse over it.

Is there a similar promise-like syntax for repeatable events like the UI event mentioned above?

Comment: Ever heard of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)?

Comment: In particular, the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Comment: I don't see how promises and events mix. They are completely different things. So I don't understand what kind of thing you want.

Comment: What you are searching for is Functional Reactive Programming, which abstracts events into streams and allows you to compose them.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Nope, jQuery uses plain old boring callbacks.